# Variables mixed between unordered categories and ordinal

Tags: categorical-data, random-variable, ordinal-data

How do we handle variables that are mixed between unordered and ordered categories? For instance, if we have a group of executives who are either CFO, COO, or CEO, we might think that CFO and COO are distinct categories but not in any particular order. CEO, however, ranks above them.

Another example could be military ranks in different services. A general and an admiral are different, but neither outranks the other. However, both outrank a lieutenant. (Another interesting issue could be that Army and Navy captains are dramatically different ranks despite using the same name, but that's for another time.)

What kind of variable is this, and how would we handle it in a statistical analysis? It is not an ordinal variable, since there is no order difference between COO and CFO. However, to treat it as purely categorical ignores the fact that the CEO outranks the COO and CFO.

Comment: I guess it depends on the analysis you want to do. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I don’t have a particular application in mind. Maybe some hybrid of classification and ordinal regression?